# Ubuntu 21.04 Broke Passwordless SSH Shutdown

Tags: ssh, shutdown, visudo

I recently had passwordless SSH shutdown and reboot working on Ubuntu 20.04, but after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04 it no longer works.

I have key based authentication set up correctly, and can ssh into the Ubuntu 21.04 computer without a password.  But my passwordless shutdown and reboot commands no longer work.

My /etc/sudoers file has the following as the last entry:

[USERNAME] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/shutdown /usr/sbin/reboot

I have tried various iterations for the sudoers file that I found on the web (some of which have commas between the reboot and shutdown entries, some of which just say /sbin instead of /usr/sbin) but nothing works.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is QA-tested to upgrade two ways; to the next release (ie. 20.10) OR *will be in the future* to the next LTS release (ie. 22.04 after 22.04.1 has been released).  You've gone outside of those paths, so *testing* of your chosen path was on you.  I'd suggest sticking to fully QA & supported paths for the best upgrades.

Comment: Don't try random advises from Internet. Check where shutdown and reboot reside, use that path. If you try `man sudoers` you will find they need to be comma separated

Comment: guiverc - Canonical describes 21.04 as a "production quality" release and even though it is not LTS it is still within the support window.  Also, I had no choice but to upgrade.  Just bought a new CPU that was incompatible with 20.04.  I needed the updated Linux kernel, so I had no choice but to upgrade.  marosg - thanks for the advice.  It fixed the problem.

Comment: The 21.04 kernel stack is available for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (at 20.04.3 machines using the HWE kernel stack use 21.04 stack; at 20.04.2 they used the 20.10 stack; users who opted to use GA stack remain on 20.04's *stable* kernel - selected at installed via menu or ISO used to install, but can be changed post-install anyway). Don't forget LTS releases offer two kernel stack choices!   (also be aware dates on 20.04.3 eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ apply to ISOs, installed systems upgraded ~fornight earlier)